# clojure core.async - unexpected inconsistencies

Tags: clojure, core.async

haven't done any Clojure for couple years, so decided to go back and not ignore core.async this time around ) pretty cool stuff, that - but it surprised me almost immediately. Now, I understand that there's inherent indeterminism when multiple threads are involved, but there's something bigger than that at play here.

The source code for my oh-so-simple example, where I am trying to copy lines from STDIN to a file:

```
(defn append-to-file
  "Write a string to the end of a file"
  ([filename s]
   (spit filename (str s "\n")
         :append true))
  ([s]
   (append-to-file "/tmp/journal.txt" s)))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "Initializing..")
  (let [out-chan (a/chan)]
    (loop [line (read-line)]
      (if (empty? line) :ok
          (do
            (go (>! out-chan line))
            (go (append-to-file (<! out-chan)))
            (recur (read-line)))))))
```

except, of course, this turned out to be not so simple. I think I've narrowed it down to *something* that's not properly cleaned up. Basically, running the main function produces inconsistent results. Sometimes I run it 4 times, and see 12 lines in the output. But sometimes, 4 run will produce just 10 lines. Or like below, 3 times, 6 lines:

```
akamac.home ➜  coras git:(master) ✗ make clean
cat /dev/null > /tmp/journal.txt
lein clean
akamac.home ➜  coras git:(master) ✗ make compile
lein uberjar
Compiling coras.core
Created /Users/akarpov/repos/coras/target/uberjar/coras-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created /Users/akarpov/repos/coras/target/uberjar/coras-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
akamac.home ➜  coras git:(master) ✗ make run    
java -jar target/uberjar/coras-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar < resources/input.txt
Initializing..
akamac.home ➜  coras git:(master) ✗ make run
java -jar target/uberjar/coras-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar < resources/input.txt
Initializing..
akamac.home ➜  coras git:(master) ✗ make run
java -jar target/uberjar/coras-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar < resources/input.txt
Initializing..
akamac.home ➜  coras git:(master) ✗ make check  
cat /tmp/journal.txt
line a
line z
line b
line a
line b
line z
```

(Basically, sometimes a run produced 3 lines, sometimes 0, sometimes 1 or 2).
The fact that lines appear in random order doesn't bother me - go blocks do things in a concurrent/threaded manner, and all bets are off. But why they don't do *all* of work *all* the time? (Because I am misusing them somehow, but where?)
Thanks!

Comment: the one thing I am suspicious of is this: after I enqueue a message in the channel, I don't know how long it'll take for a thread from a go block to pick it up and do it's work. And since I don't block on anything, the main thread might terminate before a go-block's threa gets a chance to do the work. So there's a race condition...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you've a point. I forgot I'm limited in "accepting" my own answers by 2 days - but not in _providing_ it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's many problems with this code, let me walk through them real quick:

1) Every time you call `(go ...)` you're spinning of a new "thread" that will be executed in a thread pool. It is undefined when this thread will run.

2) You aren't waiting for the completion of these threads, so it's possible (and very likely) that you will end up reading several lines form the file, writing several lines to the channel, before a read even occurs.

3) You are firing off multiple calls to `append-to-file` at the same time (see #2) these functions are not synchronized, so it's possible that multiple threads will append at once. Since access to files in most OSes is uncoordinated it's possible for two threads to write to your file at the same time, overwriting eachother's results.

4) Since you are creating a new `go` block for every line read, it's possible they will execute in a different order than you expect, this means the lines in the output file may be out of order.

I think all this can be fixed a bit by avoiding a rather common anti-pattern with core.async: don't create `go` blocks (or threads) inside unbounded or large loops. Often this is doing something you don't expect. Instead create one `core.async/thread` with a loop that reads from the file (since it's doing IO, never do IO inside a `go` block) and writes to the channel, and one that reads from the channel and writes to the output file.

View this as an assembly line build out of workers (`go` blocks) and conveyor belts (channels). If you built a factory you wouldn't have a pile of people and pair them up saying "you take one item, when you're done hand it to him". Instead you'd organize all the people once, with conveyors between them and "flow" the work (or data) between the workers. Your workers should be static, and your data should be moving.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I might have solved the particular problem responsible for those particular symptoms - but sure gave a deeper answer.

Answer (score 0):

.. and of course, this was a misuse of core.async on my part:

If I care about seeing all the data in the output, I **must** use a **blocking** 'take' on the channel, when I want to pass the value to my I/O code -- and, as it was pointed out, that blocking call should not be inside a go block. A single line change was all I needed:

from:

```
(go (append-to-file (<! out-chan)))
```

to:

```
(append-to-file (<!! out-chan))
```

Comment: Don't use `<!!` inside a `go` block or inside any function called by a `go` block. This can block the `go`'s execution queue and will create really hard to debug problems.

Comment: yes this goes hand in hand with feedback provided in your answer. It seems "duh" in retrospect - blocking a worker spawned on a limited thread-pool isn't a good idea

Comment: This doesn't fix any of the fnudamental problems with your approach, as explained by Timothy Baldridge. You say in another comment that "I might have solved the particular problem", but you haven't done that: you've just perturbed things a bit so that you run into the race condition less often. The very same bug is still there.

Comment: @amalloy I have said the changes in my own answer solved the "original problem". The "original problem", as described in the question, was the race conditions observed -- "go" threads weren't given the chance to finish their jobs. For every line read, I'd spawn a go worker from a thread-pool; that worker would try to put onto an unbuffered channel; there's no one taking from the channel, and it parks. Back on main thread, I am spawning another go worker, this time taking from the channel.  There's something waiting, so these two exchange the message. Main thread goes on without waiting.

Comment: @amalloy -- that explains the problem I've had - main thread would spawn go workers to take and put for every line, and then terminate. Sometimes they'd finish that work, sometimes they wouldn't.

Comment: NOTE: I've edited the answer so it shows that my fix, however weak, didn't put a >!! inside a go block (this wasn't obvious from the way I described it)